# Problem using WarpedVRT from rasterio for warping geotiff

Tags: python, rasterio

I am new to spatial data processing in Python using rasterio and I have been working through examples. I am having problems with warping, even with the example datasets available and I am not sure where to go from here. Below is the code that I have been running (directly from the rasterio documentation) and the error that I have been receiving.

```
from affine import Affine
import mercantile

import rasterio
from rasterio.enums import Resampling
from rasterio.vrt import WarpedVRT

with rasterio.open('RGB.byte.tif') as src:
    with WarpedVRT(src, crs='EPSG:3857',
                   resampling=Resampling.bilinear) as vrt:

        # Determine the destination tile and its mercator bounds using
        # functions from the mercantile module.
        dst_tile = mercantile.tile(*vrt.lnglat(), 9)
        left, bottom, right, top = mercantile.xy_bounds(*dst_tile)

        # Determine the window to use in reading from the dataset.
        dst_window = vrt.window(left, bottom, right, top)

        # Read into a 3 x 512 x 512 array. Our output tile will be
        # 512 wide x 512 tall.
        data = vrt.read(window=dst_window, out_shape=(3, 512, 512))

        # Use the source's profile as a template for our output file.
        profile = vrt.profile
        profile['width'] = 512
        profile['height'] = 512
        profile['driver'] = 'GTiff'

        # We need determine the appropriate affine transformation matrix
        # for the dataset read window and then scale it by the dimensions
        # of the output array.
        dst_transform = vrt.window_transform(dst_window)
        scaling = Affine.scale(dst_window.num_cols / 512,
                               dst_window.num_rows / 512)
        dst_transform *= scaling
        profile['transform'] = dst_transform

        # Write the image tile to disk.
        with rasterio.open('/tmp/test-tile.tif', 'w', **profile) as dst:
            dst.write(data)
```

---

```
CPLE_BaseError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
rasterio/_crs.pyx in rasterio._crs._CRS.from_user_input()

rasterio/_err.pyx in rasterio._err.exc_wrap_ogrerr()

CPLE_BaseError: OGR Error code 6

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

CRSError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-764b8370d990> in <module>
      8 with rasterio.open('RGB.byte.tif') as src:
      9     with WarpedVRT(src, crs='EPSG:3857',
---> 10                    resampling=Resampling.bilinear) as vrt:
     11 
     12         # Determine the destination tile and its mercator bounds using

rasterio/_warp.pyx in rasterio._warp.WarpedVRTReaderBase.__init__()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rasterio/crs.py in 
from_user_input(cls, value, morph_from_esri_dialect)
    457         elif isinstance(value, string_types):
    458             obj = cls()
--> 459             obj._crs = _CRS.from_user_input(value, 
morph_from_esri_dialect=morph_from_esri_dialect)
    460             return obj
    461             else:

rasterio/_crs.pyx in rasterio._crs._CRS.from_user_input()

CRSError: The WKT could not be parsed. OGR Error code 6
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your CRS like so:

```py
from rasterio import crs
pseudo_mercator = crs.CRS.from_epsg(3857)
```

Your issue is easily replicated:

```
>>> from rasterio import crs
>>> crs.CRS.from_string('ESPG:3857')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rasterio/crs.pyx", line 775, in rasterio.crs.CRS.from_user_input
  File "rasterio/_err.pyx", line 209, in rasterio._err.exc_wrap_ogrerr
rasterio._err.CPLE_BaseError: OGR Error code 5

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "rasterio/crs.pyx", line 861, in rasterio.crs.CRS.from_string
  File "rasterio/crs.pyx", line 777, in rasterio.crs.CRS.from_user_input
rasterio.errors.CRSError: The WKT could not be parsed. OGR Error code 5
```

Because that function expects different input, such as a PROJ or WKT string.